# Port redirection on loopback with IP other than 127.0.0.1

Tags: networking, iptables, routing

I want to redirect port 80 on the loopback network interface so that accesses to that port actually go to port 8080.

I tried using the following command, but it only works if the application is listening on 127.0.0.1:8080, but not if it's listening on 127.1.2.3:8080.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

I also tried adding `--source 127.1.2.3/32 --destination 127.1.2.3/32` but it still doesn't work.

The redirection works if I open an application listening on 127.0.0.1:8080:

```
ssh remote -L127.0.0.1:8080:192.168.0.3:80

nc 127.0.0.1 80 # works
```

But it doesn't work if I open an application listening on 127.1.2.3:8080:

```
ssh remote -L127.1.2.3:8080:192.168.0.3:80

nc 127.1.2.3 80 # fails
nc: connect to 127.1.2.3 port 80 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

nc 127.1.2.3 8080 # works, so the application is still listening on 8080
```

How can I redirect the port 8080 on 127.x.x.x to the port 80 on the same IP?

**Update: Motivation**

I'm trying to use SSH to do the following port forwardings (127.1.2.3:80 → 192.168.0.3:80, and 127.1.2.4:80 → 192.168.0.4:80):

```
ssh remote -L127.1.2.3:80:192.168.0.3:80 -L127.1.2.4:80:192.168.0.4:80
```

Since port 80 is "privileged", ssh can't open it on localhost. There are several ways to circumvent that:

- `sudo ssh`, but I don't want to have to copy my ssh config and keys on the root account.
- Use capabilities, but package updates may break this.
- Use a different port (e.g. 8080), that works but non-relative urls get broken.
- Reroute the privileged port to a non-privileged one, and that's what I'm trying to do. It works for a single redirection on 127.0.0.1, but it fails if I have redirections on IPs other than 127.0.0.1 (see above).

Comment: Why are you using IP 127.1.2.3 & the loopback? I don't believe these addresses are usable in this fashion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580637/iptables-redirect-from-external-interface-to-loopbacks-port

Comment: @slm Because I want to forward several applications that run on port 80 on different hosts (127.1.2.3:80 maps to 192.168.0.3:80 (on the ssh remote side), and 127.1.2.4:80 maps to 192.168.0.4:80 (on the ssh remote side)). [All 127.x.x.x addresses are reserved for loopback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface): "Various Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF) standards reserve the IPv4 address block 127.0.0.0/8 [...] The most common IPv4 address used is 127.0.0.1."

Comment: You'll need to explain what exactly it is you're doing. This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @slm I added my motivation for this question, but that's not an XY Problem, since I'm still interested in knowing how to redirect ports on the loopback interface for IPs other than 127.0.0.1, even if I find a different solution for my original problem.